# Shotwell reboots Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: shotwell

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on a brand new hard disk. My computer restarts after a few minutes I open Shotwell, which every time is importing my large Pictures library (150GB). I do have 29GB of free space in my /home, where the Pictures directory resides.

I have checked other posts about log files and none seem to point me to finding the root cause of the restarts. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: I looked at the logs and did not find anything suspicious. What am I looking for?

Comment: Well, for that motive you should show them to us ;).

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced reboots on my laptop caused by Shotwell.
The issue was Shotwell was using all four CPU cores during picture import, causing its temperature to raise up to a point where a "thermal protection reboot" -so to speak- was performed by the system.
I am unsure whether hardware CPU protection kicked in or Ubuntu (12.04) has a configurable temperature limit somewhere...
(To me that means my laptop has a cooling issue, but that's besides the point.)

The solution I used (and still use today) is limit the amount of CPU power Shotwell can use with cpulimit.

```
sudo apt-get install cpulimit
```

Then, after launching Shotwell, I open a terminal and type:

```
cpulimit  -e shotwell -l 50
```